# Can we start sentences with "to clarify"

Tags: grammar

> To clarify, this means what I think it means, right?

This is a grammatically correct sentence, right? I looked up the ways we use the word **clarify** but didn't come across many examples of the word being used at the beginning of the sentence, which why I'm confused whether this sentence is correct or not. I don't see any reason why it should be incorrect, but it's good to verify.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is nothing special about the word "clarify".  It is being used as a verb.

The phrase "To clarify" is being used adverbially.  It can be placed at the start of  a sentence (and should be separated from the subject by a comma in written language, and intonation in speech)

> To clarify, I'm not a professional programmer; I only do this as a hobby.

Adverbs, prepositional phrases and infinitives can all be placed at the start of a sentence.